# Elastic search randomly fails to execute during unit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, elasticsearch, python-unittest

I have some unit tests that run a test instance of elasticsearch using `com.github.tlrx.elasticsearch.test.EsSetup`. The tests that normally pass occasionally encounter the following exception:

```
org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: Failed to execute phase [query_fetch], all shards failed
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.onFirstPhaseResult(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:272)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction$3.onFailure(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:224)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction.sendExecuteFetch(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:307)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchQueryAndFetchAction$AsyncAction.sendExecuteFirstPhase(TransportSearchQueryAndFetchAction.java:71)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.performFirstPhase(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:216)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.performFirstPhase(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:203)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction$2.run(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Each test normally writes a small amount of data to the index, does a search and checks the results. The test that does no writes and checks that the search returns nothing seems as likely as the others to get the error.

Can anyone clarify for me what causes these errors?

Comment: I have the same issue and do not find informations on what to do. Can somebody help with infos or a link to infos?

Comment: I still haven't found any resolution for this. It happens less after I upgraded the test running hardware to a faster machine so I suspect this is some sort of race condition.

Comment: I updated elasticsearch yesterday vom 1.4.1 to 1.4.5. At first sight, the problem is gone. I will write here again, if it comes up again.

Comment: Error happens less, but persists. Does anybody have another idea? I can imagine that this has something todo with the "refresh" of elasticsearch: For my tests, i execute it quite often, so I can check if the documents have been created in the correct way.

Comment: Updated to 1.6, error is gone. Yeah!